# Accept consequent ab string - Finite State Automata

Tags: formal-languages, finite-automata

I have a problem that goes like this

> Create a finite-state machine which accepts strings whose characters are in
>   {a,b,c}
>   and produce output strings of
>   T
>   s and
>   F
>   s. The machine outputs a
>   T
>   once the character pair
>   ab
>   (the characters must be adjacent) is encountered in
>   the string. Before this occurrence, it should output
>   F
>   s. Indicate the the
>   starting state, and label the states and transitions. Give a diagram, not a state
>   table.

I just started learning this and here is my first attempt. I haven't labeled the output states ( T and F's) but I'm assuming I would only have T when I move from S1 to S2. The starting state is S0 and the accepting state is S2.

Heres a close picture 
[image]

I'm not really sure about my approach so I would like to know if I am on the right track and if I'm not, what I am doing wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The transition $s_1 \xrightarrow{a} s_0$ should be changed to a loop $s_1 \xrightarrow{a} s_1$.

Comment: please explain why?

Comment: Consider the word $aab$. It contains the factor $ab$, but it is not accepted by your automaton.